# possible values for account type and prod code

Tags: jackhenry-jxchange

What are all possible values for  a ?ccount type and prod code ?

I need to get account type and prod code buut not getting it in documentation . Do we have document for this. Can prod code be different for different environments.

Answer (score 0):

The **ParmValSrch** API (https://jackhenry.dev/open-enterprise-api-docs/enterprise-soap-api/api-reference/core-services/parmvalsrch/) will return those and other similar type values. A full list of elements that may be returned are found on the message brief page for the ParmValSrch API.

Additionally, the AcctTypes were listed in the **jXchange and SilverLake**, **jXchange and Core Director** and **jXchange and CIF 2020** pdf documents listed within the Getting Started with jXchange SOAP and Getting Started with jXchange REST-Legacy pages.